# Segment lines according to point using pgRouting

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, linear-referencing

I'm working on PostgreSQL and I am trying to create table to generate graphs. I have a table that contains all the objects of a city (points) and another contains the city street. My goal now is to segment the street in small segments that begins and ends with two objects (points).
I try with different PostgreSQL query but I can not create a table of links that restrained the source and destination of each seqments ST_pointN actually gives the first and last point in a linestring against me by I want to have all the object on a street with the order to which I may have small segments.

Can pgRouting help me segment the streets and if so how?

Comment: Please add an image to illustrate the question. Are the points located on the lines or besides them, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you should read about linear referencing.

```
ST_line_locate_point(LineString, Point) (0-1 value from start) 
ST_line_interpolate_point(linestring, location)
```

using those two you get nearest point on road from your point. After that split edges to have node for those point and regenerate graph table